# Changing text of a Button in Unity upon loading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just trying to edit a Button's text on my Unity app whenever the game loads.

```
ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Text' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
```

Below is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using UnityEngine.UI;

internal class Text
{
    internal string text;
}



public class Backend : MonoBheaviour
{
  
  void Start()
    {
        GameObject.Find("Option 1 Button").GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Sdfsdfsd";

        PopulateHeadlines();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you defining `Text` class, `UnityEngine.UI` has a `Text` class already just use that

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `internal class Text` hide the `UnityEngine.UI.Text`.

Delete your definition and try again.